# Android sendtextmessage doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I'm trying to send an SMS from my `Service`. It works on some devices and does not work on others.
I tried the following ways to send an SMS:

first variant:

```
  SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
  manager.sendTextMessage(number, null,text,null, null);
```

second variant:

```
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 0,new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0); 
    SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(number, null,text,sentPI, null);
```

third variant:

```
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 0,new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0); 
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 0,new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
    SmsManager manager=SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(number, null,text,sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

It works on the following devices:

- HTC Desire 200
- HTC Sensation Z710e

But it doesn't work on:

- HTC Desire V
- HTC Wildfire S

What I should do to use sendind sms on all devices?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help you, but I've found that `sendTextMessage()` can fail silently unless it's called from within an Activity. I've not figured out why yet, but the only consistently reliable solution I've come up with is to start an Activity to send the SMS. In my case, I create the Activity with a Dialog Theme, and `finish()` right after the send, so it looks just like a little pop-up notification.

Comment: @MikeM. Good variant. Thank you

Comment: @Artem did mikes advice solve your problem? I am facing the same problem right now...

Comment: @artworkadシ I used some library. If I not mistaken, this - https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms